# Gulp: The build process from the src directory to the build directory

Tags: javascript, gulp, build-process

I'm using gulpjs to set up a build process. My src/ folder has many files and folders (mainly PHP but some image files and CSS). My build/ directory is currently empty.

I've created a task which optimizes image files in src/images and places them in build/images.

```
// gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('images', function() {
    gulp.src('src/images/**/*')
        .pipe(changed('build/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'));
});
gulp.task('default', ['images']);
```

As you can see, my build process is incomplete because my build/ directory now just contains my optimised images.

```
/build
    images/
```

What is the standard way to complete a *full* build so that my build/ directory is complete with all the files from my src/ directory? Please forgive the noob question, I'm just getting started learning about the build process.

My guess is, I'd set up a watch task in gulp which copies everything from src/ to build/ if changes are detected but I'd appreciate some direction in case there is a standard way I'm not aware of.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you'll often need to create a task that manually copies files that don't get created by some other process.

Perhaps a `move-templates` task that just copies `*.php` to `/build`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('images', function() {
    gulp.src('src/images/**/*')
        .pipe(changed('dist/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));

gulp.task('others', function() {
    gulp.src(['src/**/*', '!src/images/**/*']) // "!" denotes to exclude images folder
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['others', 'images']);
```